# Will events happen the same in identical saves?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Recently my graphics card crashed and I was unable to save my game before I restarted. If I started back from a previous save, would events be the same, or different? Would CS's give the same quests? Would the same technologies be stolen? Same cities settled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually depends if you have chosen to have a random seed on reload or not, which you can set when creating your game in advanced mode. It is not possible to change this afterwards.

A new random seed on every load makes the outcome of battles and other things different. Default behaviour is to store the random seed in the savegame and thus, you have the same outcome every time you load.

Comment: So assuming I use default settings, would it be the same or different? This was unclear.

Comment: The same since the seed for randomness is stored in the savegame. Cities will probably still be in the same place as this depends mostly on the terrain.

Comment: Alright. So I can get ready to finish quests before they're even given and prepare for wars before they even happen?

Comment: @Crubleigh No, not necessarily. Any change you make in how you proceed in the game can result in different results, due to potentially different weightings. Maintaining the random seed will only ensure that given the same inputs, you will receive the same outputs.

Comment: @Crubleigh An example: Egypt (an AI) declares war on you at turn 50. You reload turn 40 and build some extra units. Egypt does *not* declare war on you on turn 50 this time, because "size of AI army vs. size of your army" is one of the factors that determines whether the AI declares war on you.

Answer (score 3):

As leetfan points out, the random seed is stored and reloaded from the saved game unless you enable New Random Seed in the custom game options. However, this only controls the *sequence* of random numbers generated by the game. If you alter when and how often the game uses those numbers, you will change the outcome of random events including combat and game events.

> **Note:** I believe that every decision the AI makes is determined solely by its programming and doesn't require any random numbers. If that's untrue, pretty much *any* action you perform differently that an AI can see could alter the game.

For example, in the early game you make very few decisions that can alter the flow of the game. But let's say you attack two barbarian units during a turn.

- First you attacked with your Warrior and then your Archer, and this required five die rolls followed by three.
- After reloading you reverse the order of the attacks, but this time while the die rolls themselves have not changed, attacking with the Archer first requires four rolls while the Warrior still requires five.

You've now used one more random number, and this can completely change the outcome of events. Imagine a game of craps in Vegas with fourteen people around the table making bets and rolling the dice. If you were to take the exact same sequence of die rolls and replay them, assuming everyone bet the same, the final tallies at the end would remain unchanged. Now do that again, except knock out one or two die rolls in the sequence.

Comment: Pretty much the same things happened (The Celts declared war on Vatican city for some retarded reason, and they couldn't even get units there because I had it surrounded)